# setsockopt does not work within docker container

Tags: c, linux, docker

I have create a MQPRIO qdisc configuration as shown

```bash
sudo tc qdisc add dev p2p2 parent root handle 1 mqprio \
        num_tc 3 \
        map 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 \
        queues 1@0 1@1 1@2 \
        hw 0
```

I have created a script that uses SO_PRIORITY to set skb->priority so MQPRIO can enqueue the packet to the right queue. In our setup, we have 3 queues. Specifically, a skb->priority of three should be sent to the first queue. Below is the line of code that sets socket priority.

```cpp
 if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PRIORITY, &prio, sizeof(prio)) < 0)
 {
     perror("setsockopt");
     return 1;
 }
```

This works fine when run on the host (without container). All packets with a SO_PRIORITY set to 3, (more specifically skb->priority). However, when the program is called inside a docker container using the default networking options (docker0), all packets are sent to the third qdisc. After some debugging, I found that no matter what priority was set, all of the packets were sent to the third queue. Only when I configured the map's first entry to zero, then the packet was sent to the first queue.

For example, if I send 1000 packets with priorities 3, 2, and 1, we get

```
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent 1:3 bands 3 priomap 1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 55168 bytes 1004 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent 1:2 bands 3 priomap 1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 55000 bytes 1000 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent 1:1 bands 3 priomap 1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 55000 bytes 1000 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

which is correct (the four extra packets are arp packets).

However, when running in a container, we get

```
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent 1:3 bands 3 priomap 1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 165126 bytes 3003 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent 1:2 bands 3 priomap 1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent 1:1 bands 3 priomap 1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

This means that the skb->priority was in fact not set and is still the default 0.

***Is there any way to call setsockopt with the SO_PROIORITY within a container so that it can be properly classified by the MQPRIO qdsics?***

I know that using the -net=host options solves this. I also know that we can use TOS or filters to flow traffic to the correct queue instead, but I want to know if this is doable with SO_PRIORITY.

Comment: So the `setsockopt()` call is returning success (`0`) inside the container, but the priority seems unchanged, right?

Comment: Yes, it is returning success.